# Reverse Sobolev embedding for H^s

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Assume that we are on a bounded domain with a smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I know that for $2m > n$ we have the embedding
$$
 H^{m+j} \subset C^j,j=0,1,\dots,n.
$$
Is there any way to show the following reverse relation?
$$
 C^k \subset H^{l}
$$

Specifically, I am thinking of $n = 2$ and I want to show that
$$
 H^3 \subset C^1 \subset H^2.
$$
(The first part is done from the first embedding.)

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a counterexample is given by $f(x):=x^{3/2}$ on $[0,1]$ (it works for higher dimensions too,  simply make it not depend on additional components of $x$)